# Trigonometric polynomial is Fourier series expandable.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

**Definition**

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be a function with period $2l$ and Lebesgue integrable on $[-l, l].$

Then, define $S_N[f] : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ by $S_N [f](x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=-N}^N c_k (f) e^{ik\omega x} ,$ where $\omega=\dfrac{\pi}{l}$ and $c_k(f)=\dfrac{1}{2l}\displaystyle\int_{-l}^l f(s) e^{-ik\omega s} \ \ ds$.

Then, $f$ is Fourier series expandable in $L^2([-l,l]) $ $\underset{\mathrm{def}}\iff$  $\| S_N[f]-f \|_{L^2([-l,l])} \to 0 $ as $N \to \infty$

---

Then, I want to prove that all
trigonometric polynomials are Fourier series expandable.

---

Let $g$ be a trigonometric polynomial.

Then, there exists $M \in \mathbb N, \{a_j \}_{j=1}^M \subset \mathbb C, \{ k_j \}_{j=1}^M \subset \mathbb Z$

such that  $k_j \neq k_l$ for $j\neq l$ and $g(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^M a_j e^{ik_j\ \omega x}$.

First, I consider $S_N [g](x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=-N}^N c_k (g) e^{ik\omega x}$.

\begin{align}
c_k(g)
&=\dfrac{1}{2l}\int_{-l}^l g(s) e^{-ik\omega s} \ ds \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^M a_j \cdot \dfrac{1}{2l} \int_{-l}^l e^{i(k_j-k) \omega s}\ \  ds. 
\end{align}

Thus,
\begin{align}
S_N [g](x)
&=\displaystyle\sum_{k=-N}^N c_k (g) e^{ik\omega x} \\
&=\sum_{k=-N}^N \ \Bigg[ \sum_{j=1}^M a_j \cdot \dfrac{1}{2l} \int_{-l}^l e^{i(k_j-k) \omega s}\ \  ds \cdot e^{ik\omega x}\ \Bigg]. \cdots (\ast)
\end{align}

And
\begin{align}
\| S_N[g]-g \|_{L^2([-l,l])}
&=\int_{-l}^l |S_N[g](x)-g(x)|^2 \ dx
\end{align}
So I have to consider $|S_N[g](x)-g(x)|
=\left| 
\displaystyle\sum_{k=-N}^N \ \Bigg[ \sum_{j=1}^M a_j \cdot \dfrac{1}{2l} \int_{-l}^l e^{i(k_j-k) \omega s}\ \  ds \cdot e^{ik\omega x}\ \Bigg]
-
\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^M a_j e^{ik_j\ \omega x}
\right|$

but this is too complicated and I don't know how I can proceed. I think that in order to simplify $(\ast)$, I can use
$$\dfrac{1}{2l} \int_{-l}^l e^{i(p-q) \omega x}\ =
\begin{cases}
0\ \mathrm{if} \ p\neq q \\
1\  \mathrm{if} \ p=q
\end{cases}$$
but I have no idea how I could process $(\ast)$ using this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to simplify the integral $\int_{-l}^l e^{i(k_j-k) \omega s} ds$. Apply the formula that you stated at the end.

Comment: I tried and I found $(\ast)=\sum_{j=1}^M a_j e^{ik_j \omega x}$. Is this corenct ? If this is correct, I can come to conclusion. @WhatsUp

Comment: Yes, that's correct as long as $N$ is larger than all the $|k_j|$.

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation.